# How to model facebook posts in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am newbie to cassandra. I am trying to design a table in cassandra which stores data of facebook posts.

It contains

`user_id,post_id,post_data,comments_details,likes_details, comments_count and likes_counts`.

I took `user_id and Post_Id` as `Partitioning key`

I am using User defined data type to store JSON data which contains `list of map types` for `comments_details` field

```
{
  "comments_details": [
    {
      "created_time": "2016-06-29T09:05:06+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "user_1",
        "id": "14465295694"
      },
      "message": "Hello How are you",
      "can_remove": false,
      "like_count": 1,
      "user_likes": true,
      "id": "174022481_674622404"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2016-06-29T09:05:14+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "user2",
        "id": "144652387"
      },
      "message": "hjhjh",
      "can_remove": false,
      "like_count": 0,
      "user_likes": false,
      "id": "17402248_6752892070"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this the right way to do it in a single table or can i go for create another table for comments_details and likes_details. I also want to count no of comments for that post.

Please help..

Answer (score 2):

Data modeling in Cassandra depends heavily on the queries you plan to run the most. So first, we should be talking about a right data model **relative to** a particular set of queries.

[Here](http://www.cs.wayne.edu/andrey/papers/TR-BIGDATA-05-2015-CKL.pdf) there's a really good article I suggest you if you just started with Cassandra. It presents an automated tool for data modeling, but explains also briefly and precisely the basic principles behind good data modeling.

In general, you want your app to satisfy its data needs with the least possible partitions accesses. How data is red plays an important part: as an example, if the app main requirement was to load the most recent posts of a given user, we would decide for example to use user_id as partition key, and the post date as clustering key to get the latest n posts with a single partition access. Other aspect to consider is the tradeoff between flexibility and data distribution. In other words, consider your specific set of queries and access patterns, then start from there.